# Python C interface, different modules share static variables?

Tags: python, c++, c, static, shared-libraries

I am building python bindings for my custom C++ lib, in Linux, using gcc 4.8.2 and Python 2.7.
I have the following folder structure within my code

```
module/
  __init__.py  
  submodule1.so # first part of lib
  submodule2.so # second part of lib
  submodule3.py # additional python tools
```

In `__init__.py`

```
import submodule1, submodule2 submodule3
```

I need to pass C++ pointers corresponding to static class member variables between submodule1 and submodule2. 
I have been using `capsules` for that purpose. Basically in submodule1 I have a `PyObject * exportCapsule()` function and in submodule2 I have an `importCapsule(PyObject *)`

Now, I found out I did not need to use those functions, and I wanted  to understand why. 
I received an explanation from John Bollinger (see response below), regarding the fact that different Python modules share same namespace for static class member variables.

I wrapped a full setup for the record as follows:

File `singleton.hpp` defines static class member for singleton like behavior::

```
#ifndef _SINGLETON_HPP
#define _SINGLETON_HPP

// Singleton.hpp

// declaration of class
// + many more things

template<typename T>
class Singleton
{
private:
  static T * _ptrInstance;

public:
  static void setInstance(T* p) 
  {
    _ptrInstance = p;
  }

  static bool doesInstanceExist() 
  {
    bool output = not(NULL == _ptrInstance);
    return output;
  }

  static T* getInstance()
  {
    return _ptrInstance;
  }
};

// declaration of static class
template<typename T>
T * Singleton<T>::_ptrInstance(NULL);

#endif
```

File submodule1.cpp defines the first module::

```
//submodule1.cpp

#include <Python.h>
#include "singleton.hpp"

static PyObject*errorObject;


PyObject *  exportCapsule(PyObject *dummy, PyObject *args)
{
  long * ptr = Singleton<long>::getInstance();

  const char * caps_name = "ptrInstance";
  return PyCapsule_New((void *)ptr, caps_name, NULL);
}

PyObject* setValue(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
  if(not(Singleton<long>::doesInstanceExist()))
  {

    // printf("Singleton ptr %p \n",Singleton<long>::getInstance());
    // printf("Singleton is null %d \n",NULL==Singleton<long>::getInstance());
    PyErr_SetString(errorObject, "Singleton does not exist");
    return NULL;
  }


  PyObject * input;
  PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &input);

  if (!PyLong_Check(input))
  {
    PyErr_SetString(errorObject, "Input should be a long integer");
    return NULL;
  }


  long * ptr = Singleton<long>::getInstance();
  *ptr = PyLong_AsLong(input);

  Py_INCREF(Py_None);
  return Py_None;
}



PyMethodDef fonctions[] = {
  {"setValue", setValue, METH_VARARGS, "set singleton value from long "},
  {"exportCapsule", exportCapsule, METH_VARARGS, "export singleton"},
  {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};


PyMODINIT_FUNC initsubmodule1(void)
{

  PyObject* m = Py_InitModule("submodule1", fonctions);

  errorObject = PyErr_NewException("submodule1.Exception", NULL, NULL);

  Py_INCREF(errorObject);
  PyModule_AddObject(m, "Exception",errorObject);


  long * ptr = new long(0);
  Singleton<long>::setInstance(ptr);
}
```

File `submodule2.cpp` defines the second module::

```
//submodule2.cpp

#include <Python.h>
#include "singleton.hpp"

static PyObject*errorObject;


// to be checked
PyObject *  importCapsule(PyObject *dummy, PyObject *args)
{


  const char * caps_name = "ptrInstance";

  PyObject * caps;
  PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &caps);

  // we should also check the name... laziness
  if (not(PyCapsule_CheckExact(caps)))
  {
    PyErr_SetString(errorObject, "Input is not a capsule");
    return NULL;
  }


  long * ptr = (long *) PyCapsule_GetPointer(caps, caps_name);

  // if we want to set the same pointer it is ok
  if (Singleton<long>::doesInstanceExist());
  {
    long * ptrPrevious = Singleton<long>::getInstance();



    if (not(ptr == ptrPrevious))
    {
      PyErr_SetString(errorObject, "You've asked for setting the global ptr with a different value");
      return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
      PyErr_SetString(errorObject, "You've asked for setting the global ptr with same value");
      return NULL;

    }
  }

  Singleton<long>::setInstance(ptr);

  Py_INCREF(Py_None);
  return Py_None;

}


PyObject* getValue(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
  if (not(Singleton<long>::doesInstanceExist()))
  {
    PyErr_SetString(errorObject, "Singleton does not exist");
    return NULL;
  }

  long val = *Singleton<long>::getInstance();

  return PyLong_FromLong(val);
}


PyMethodDef fonctions[] = {
  {"getValue", getValue, METH_VARARGS, "get long from singleton value"},
  {"importCapsule", importCapsule, METH_VARARGS, "import singleton as capsule"},
  {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};


PyMODINIT_FUNC initsubmodule2(void)
{

  PyObject* m = Py_InitModule("submodule2", fonctions);

  errorObject = PyErr_NewException("submodule2.Exception", NULL, NULL);

  Py_INCREF(errorObject);
  PyModule_AddObject(m, "Exception", errorObject);


}
```

File `setup_submodule1.py` for building first module::

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

submodule1 = Extension('submodule1', sources = ['submodule1.cpp'])

setup (name = 'PackageName',
        version = '1.0',
        description = 'This is a demo package',
        ext_modules = [submodule1])
```

File `setup_submodule2.py` for building second module::

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

submodule2 = Extension('submodule2', sources = ['submodule2.cpp'])

setup (name = 'PackageName',
        version = '1.0',
        description = 'This is a demo package',
        ext_modules = [submodule2])
```

File `test.py` for testing purpose::

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    print '----------------------------------------------'
    print 'import submodule2'
    print 'submodule2.getValue()'

    import submodule2

    try:
        submodule2.getValue()
    except Exception, e:
        print '   ## catched :', e

    print '----------------------------------------------'
    print 'import submodule1'
    print 'submodule1.setValue(1L)'

    import submodule1
    submodule1.setValue(1L)
    print 'submodule2.getValue() ->', submodule2.getValue()

    print '----------------------------------------------'
    print 'capsule = submodule1.exportCapsule()'
    print 'submodule2.importCapsule(capsule)'

    capsule = submodule1.exportCapsule()

    try:
        submodule2.importCapsule(capsule)
    except Exception, e:
        print '   ## catched :', e
```

File `Makefile` for chaining everything::

```
submodule1:
  python setup_submodule1.py  build_ext --inplace

submodule2:
  python setup_submodule2.py  build_ext --inplace

test:
  python test.py

all: submodule1 submodule2 test
```

And `make all` outputs::

```
python test.py
----------------------------------------------
import submodule2
submodule2.getValue()
   ## catched : Singleton does not exist
----------------------------------------------
import submodule1
submodule1.setValue(1L)
submodule2.getValue() -> 1
----------------------------------------------
capsule = submodule1.exportCapsule()
submodule2.importCapsule(capsule)
   ## catched : You've asked for setting the global ptr with same value
```

The original question was:

> After compilation, I have two different modules `submodule1.so` and `submodule2.so`. 
>   I can import them, and what I dont understand, is that my capsule stuff is not required. The two modules share the static variable `Singleton<myClass>::_ptrInstance`, without having to use the capsule export and import.
>
> I suspect that it has to do with the symbols within both `*.so`. If I call `nm -g *.so` I can see identical symbols.
>
> I am really amazed that two independently compiled modules can share a variable. Is it normal ?

I received a clear answer : The two modules share the variables since the namespace is common for all modules, while i was expecting different namespaces.

Comment: Is `template<typename T> T * Singleton<T>::_ptrInstance(NULL);` actually in a header?  That shouldn't work.

Comment: Following your remark, I updated the question with a full setup. You can find all files needed for reproducting my experiments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of C++ `static` member variables is that they are shared among all instances of their class.  In fact, they do not belong to any instance, but rather to the class itself.  They are essentially a form of namespaced global variable.

"All instances" means all instances *in the whole program*, and for Python modules, the whole program is the Python interpreter (i.e. not individual modules).

Do not confuse static *member* variables with static *file-scope* variables, however.  Their semantics are quite different -- nearly opposite, in fact.  File-scope variables normally have external linkage, meaning the declared name refers to that variable anywhere it appears in the whole program source, however that source is divided among files.  On the other hand, `static` file-scope variables have static linkage, which means that the declared name refers to that variable only within the compilation unit in which the declaration appears.

Takeaway: `static` member variables are global, whereas `static` file-scope variables are local.  Welcome to C++.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick answer. I was aware of the ``static`` member behavior. However, I was believing that different module would have different namespace....